# How to use Gmail contacts on an iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch, gmail, contacts, exchange

I have an iPod Touch 4. It easily lets me set up the Mail and Calendar apps to use my Gmail account, but I can't seem to find a way to get the Contacts app to use my Gmail contacts. Am I missing something or is it not possible?  Seems silly that it wouldn't let me use my Gmail contacts with my Gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it up with Google Sync.  There's a step-by-step guide on the [Google Sync Support Page](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=14252&answer=138740)

Comment: Thanks. Not sure I understand why I need to set up an Exchane account to sync my contacts when rhe default ios mail and calendar apps sync with my google account. Why isnt the contacts app set up the same way? I can't believe it didn't occur to them that you would want the contacts that go with your mail account.